# Animating GridView with jQuery in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a button on my home page... OnClick I'm getting data from the database and binding it to my GridView. I want to "SlideDown" the GridView on ButtonClick. This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ShowAllRecordsBtn").click(function() {
        $("#GridView1").slideDown(100);
    });
});
```

And I have my GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" GridLines="None" Style="z-index: 1;
    left: 65px; top: 93px; position: absolute; height: 180px; width: 304px" AutoGenerateEditButton="false"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" DataKeyNames="EmpId"
    OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting1" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" ForeColor="#333333">
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="ID"></asp:Label>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpId" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%#Eval("EmpId") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="txtEmpId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EmpId") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EmpName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="txtEmpName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EmpName")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Address"></asp:Label>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpAdd" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EmpAdd") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="txtEmpAdd" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EmpAdd")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Age"></asp:Label>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpAge" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EmpAge") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="txtEmpAge" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EmpAge")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("EmpId") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The "SlideDown" doesn't take effect! Why?

Comment: You want to bind and animate the grid view on the button click.

Comment: Does the slide effect keep your gridview header fixed? or does the header disappear with sliding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the GridView inside a DIV tag and try to animate. Because the Id of the ServerSideControl in your case `<asp:GridView>` will be changed when the page is rendered.

```
<div id="divGrid">
  <asp:GridView>
  </asp:GridView>
</div>

 $("#ShowAllRecordsBtn").click(function() {
        $("#divGrid").slideDown(100);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put it like:

```
$($get('<%= GridView1.ClientID.toString() %>')).slideDown(100);
```